# Saving Django multiple model instances using a population script only saves the instances created in the last iteration

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make some practice with Django and write a simple blog application. I want to create my models using a script so I don't have to use the shell or the admin interface.

Given the following code:

```
def populate():
    current_user = User.objects.get(username='testuser')
    blogger_data = {'user': current_user,'bio':"this is my test bio", 'likes': 5,}
    blogger = add_blogger(blogger_data)

    print("Registered blogger : %s" %blogger.user)
    for num in range(5):
        post_data = {'author':current_user, 'title':"test title %s"%num, 'description': "test description%s"%num, 'content': "test content%s"%num,}
        posted_date = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        post = add_post(post_data,num,posted_date)
        comment_data = {'author':current_user, 'post':post,'content':"test content %s"%num, 'upvotes':num, 'downvotes':5-num,}
        comment = add_comment(comment_data)
        response_data = {'author':current_user, 'comment':comment, 'content':"test response %s"%num, 'upvotes':5-num, 'downvotes':num,}
        response = add_response(response_data)
        print("Saved post : %s, comment: %s, response: %s..." %(post,comment,response))
    print("Script succesfully saved data!")

def add_post(data_dict,views, posted_date):
    post = Post.objects.get_or_create(author=data_dict['author'])[0]
    post.title = data_dict['title']
    post.description = data_dict['description']
    post.content =  data_dict['content']
    post.views = views
    post.posted_date = posted_date
    post.save()
    return post

def add_comment(data_dict):
    c = Comment.objects.get_or_create(author=data_dict['author'],post=data_dict['post'])[0]
    c.content = data_dict['content']
    c.upvotes = data_dict['upvotes']
    c.downvotes = data_dict['downvotes']
    c.save()
    return c

def add_response(data_dict):
    r = Response.objects.get_or_create(author=data_dict['author'],comment=data_dict['comment'])[0]
    r.content = data_dict['content']
    r.upvotes = data_dict['upvotes']
    r.downvotes = data_dict['downvotes']
    r.save()
    return r

def add_blogger(data_dict):
    blogger = Blogger.objects.get_or_create(user=data_dict['user'])[0]
    blogger.bio = data_dict['bio']
    blogger.likes = data_dict['likes']
    blogger.save()
    return blogger

if __name__=='__main__':
    print("Starting Blog population script...")
populate()
```

Models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, help_text="The post's title.", unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="A short description of the post.")
    content = models.CharField(max_length=8192, help_text="Your post content.")
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    posted_date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        if not self.posted_date:
            self.posted_date = datetime.today()
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s (%s)(%s)"%(self.content[:20]+"...",self.post,self.author)

class Response(models.Model):
    author = models.OneToOneField(User,primary_key=True)
    comment= models.ForeignKey(Comment, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1024, help_text="Your message in response to a desired comment.")
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s (%s)(%s)" % (self.content[:20]+"...",self.author,self.content)

class Blogger(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=1024, help_text="A short bio that viewers can see about you.")
    profilepic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profilepics')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    joined_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.joined_date = timezone.now()
        super(Blogger, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

After running the script only the model instances created in the last iteration of the loop are being saved in the database.
What is actually happening?

Comment: You'll need to show the `add_post`, `add_comment` and `add_response` functions. Posting the models would be helpful too.

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one user, which you use in every iteration. That means that your `get_or_create` call on Post will create the post for that user in the first iteration, but in every subsequent iteration will get the existing instance and update it. The subsequent calls for the rest of the functions will then do the same thing as they are passed the Post and Comment in turn.